# How to create a vertical line that connects 2 different items in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I need to create a vertical line that should connect 2 items on recyclerview.

Following is my recycler view item.

[image]

and this is what I am getting when I run this on device.

[image]

What i want is to keep that red line start from first component and end on second component

Something like following.

[image]

I need to know is there any possibility to keep some item that can present over multiple recyclerview components.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the one you are looking for.
Use this Library

https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View

> Android Timeline View Library (Using RecyclerView) is simple implementation used to display view like Tracking of shipment/order, steppers etc.

[Sample App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.vipulasri.timelineview.sample)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to achieve brackets style layout. I used following library, it gives me the animation, but i also need to place a bracket component. 

https://github.com/Emil333/TournamentBrackets

Comment: Bracket view:  https://ewscripps.brightspotcdn.com/dims4/default/1a58e25/2147483647/strip/true/crop/622x350+0+65/resize/1280x720!/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmediaassets.3newsnow.com%2Fphoto%2F2018%2F05%2F19%2FBIG%20TEN%20BRACKET_1526783324187.jpg_87486020_ver1.0_640_480.jpg